# AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'get_json'

Tags: python, html, ajax, flask

it was working before I merged the source
this is the first source I try

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify
from random import random
from flask.globals import request
from flask.templating import render_template
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model

model = load_model('models/20201213_202430.h5')

app = Flask(__name__, static_url_path='', static_folder='static')


@app.route('/omok')
def omok():
    return render_template('omok05_ai.html')


@app.route('/ajaxtest')
def ajaxtest():
    return render_template('ajaxtest.html')


#===============================================================================
@app.route('/ajax_omok', methods=['POST'])
def ajax_omok():
    data = request.get_json()
    stones = data['stones']
    arr_stone = stones.split(',')
    print(arr_stone)
    input = []
    for s in arr_stone:
        input.append(int(s))
    
    input_n = np.array(input)
    input_n = np.reshape(input_n,(1,20,20,1))
    output = model.predict(input_n).squeeze()
    
    cnt = np.argmax(output)
    
    i = int(cnt/20)
    j = int(cnt%20)
    
    print(i,j)
    return jsonify(i = i, j = j)

#===============================================================================

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0", debug=True)
```

this was the html source

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>OMOK</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
// var comput_i = 0;
// var computs = [
//         {"i":0,"j":0},
//         {"i":0,"j":1},
//         {"i":0,"j":2},
//         {"i":0,"j":3},
//         {"i":0,"j":4}
//     ]

var flag_wb = true;
var flag_over = false;
var arr2d = [
   [0,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,0],
   [0,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,0],
   [0,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,0],
   [0,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,0],
   [0,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,0],

   [0,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,0],
   [0,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,0],
   [0,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,0],
   [0,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,0],
   [0,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,0],
   
   [0,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,0],
   [0,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,0],
   [0,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,0],
   [0,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,0],
   [0,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,0],
   
   [0,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,0],
   [0,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,0],
   [0,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,0],
   [0,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,0],
   [0,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,0]
];

function aiinit(){

}

function myinit() {
   var stns = document.getElementsByClassName("stn");
   for(var i=0; i<20; i++) {
      for(var j=0; j<20; j++) {
         stns[i*20+j].alt = i+","+j;
      }
   }
}

function myrender() {
   var stns = document.getElementsByClassName("stn");
   for(var i=0; i<20; i++) {
      for(var j=0; j<20; j++) {
         if(arr2d[i][j] == 0) {
            stns[i*20+j].src = "0.png"
         }
         if(arr2d[i][j] == 1) {
            stns[i*20+j].src = "1.png"
         }
         if(arr2d[i][j] == 2) {
            stns[i*20+j].src = "2.png"
         }
      }
   }
}

function myreset(){
    var stns = document.getElementsByClassName("stn");
    for(var i=0; i<20; i++) {
          for(var j=0; j<20; j++) {
              arr2d[i][j]=0;
              stns[i*20+j].src = "0.png"
          }
    }
    flag_over = false;
    flag_wb = true;
}

function myclick(obj) {
   if(flag_over) {
      return;
   }
   
   var str = obj.alt;
   var arr = str.split(",");
   
   var i = parseInt(arr[0]);
   var j = parseInt(arr[1]);
   if(arr2d[i][j] > 0) {
      return;
   }
   
   var stone = -1;
   if (flag_wb) {
      arr2d[i][j] = 1;
      stone = 1;
   } else {      
      arr2d[i][j] = 2;
      stone = 2;
   }
   
   var up = checkUp(i,j,stone);
   var dw = checkDw(i,j,stone);
   var ri = checkRi(i,j,stone);
   var le = checkLe(i,j,stone);

   var ur = checkUr(i,j,stone);
   var ul = checkUl(i,j,stone);
   var dr = checkDr(i,j,stone);
   var dl = checkDl(i,j,stone);
   
   var d1 = up+dw+1;
   var d2 = le+ri+1;
   var d3 = ul+dr+1;
   var d4 = ur+dl+1;
   
   myrender();
   
   if(d1==5 || d2==5 || d3==5 || d4==5) {
      if(flag_wb) {
          setTimeout(function(){
              alert("흰돌 승리");
          },300); 
      } else {
          setTimeout(function(){
              alert("흑돌 승리");
          },300); 
      }
      
      flag_over = true;
      return
   }
   
   flag_wb = !flag_wb;
   /*==============================*/
    var stones = arr2d+"";
    stones = stones.replace(/2/gi, "-1")
    console.log(stones)

    var postdata = {
        'stones' : stones
    }
    console.log(postdata)
    var iii
    var jjj
    $.ajax({
        url : "ajax_omok",
        data : JSON.stringify(postdata),
        dataType : "json",
        type : "post",
        contentType : "application/json",
        async : false,
        statusCode : {
            404 : function() {
                alert("네트워크가 불안정합니다. 다시 시도부탁드립니다.");
            }
        },
        success : function(data) {
            console.log(data);
            console.log(data['i']);
            console.log(data['j']);
            iii = data['i']
            jjj = data['j']
        }
    });
    console.log(iii)    
    console.log(jjj)
   var i = iii;
   var j = jjj;
   
   var stone = -1;
   if (flag_wb) {
      arr2d[i][j] = 1;
      stone = 1;
   } else {      
      arr2d[i][j] = 2;
      stone = 2;
   }
   
   var up = checkUp(i,j,stone);
   var dw = checkDw(i,j,stone);
   var ri = checkRi(i,j,stone);
   var le = checkLe(i,j,stone);

   var ur = checkUr(i,j,stone);
   var ul = checkUl(i,j,stone);
   var dr = checkDr(i,j,stone);
   var dl = checkDl(i,j,stone);
   
   var d1 = up+dw+1;
   var d2 = le+ri+1;
   var d3 = ul+dr+1;
   var d4 = ur+dl+1;
   
   myrender();
   
   if(d1==5 || d2==5 || d3==5 || d4==5) {
      if(flag_wb) {
          setTimeout(function(){
              alert("흰돌 승리");
          },300); 
      } else {
          setTimeout(function(){
              alert("흑돌 승리");
          },300); 
      }
      
      flag_over = true;
      return
   }
   
   flag_wb = !flag_wb;
   comput_i++
   
   
   
   
   
   
}//end



function checkUp(i,j,stone) {
   var cnt = 0;
   
   try {
      while(true) {
         i--;
         if (arr2d[i][j] == stone) {
            cnt++;
         } else {
            return cnt;
         }
      }      
   } catch(e) {
      return cnt;
   }
   return cnt;
}
function checkDw(i,j,stone) {
   var cnt = 0;
   
   try {
      while(true) {
         i++;
         if (arr2d[i][j] == stone) {
            cnt++;
         } else {
            return cnt;
         }
      }      
   } catch(e) {
      return cnt;
   }
   return cnt;
}
function checkRi(i,j,stone) {
   var cnt = 0;
   
   try {
      while(true) {
         j++;
         if (arr2d[i][j] == stone) {
            cnt++;
         } else {
            return cnt;
         }
      }      
   } catch(e) {
      return cnt;
   }
   return cnt;
}
function checkLe(i,j,stone) {
   var cnt = 0;
   
   try {
      while(true) {
         j--;
         if (arr2d[i][j] == stone) {
            cnt++;
         } else {
            return cnt;
         }
      }      
   } catch(e) {
      return cnt;
   }
   return cnt;
}

function checkUr(i,j,stone) {
   var cnt = 0;
   
   try {
      while(true) {
         i--;
         j++;
         if (arr2d[i][j] == stone) {
            cnt++;
         } else {
            return cnt;
         }
      }      
   } catch(e) {
      return cnt;
   }
   return cnt;
}
function checkUl(i,j,stone) {
   var cnt = 0;
   
   try {
      while(true) {
         i--;
         j--;
         if (arr2d[i][j] == stone) {
            cnt++;
         } else {
            return cnt;
         }
      }      
   } catch(e) {
      return cnt;
   }
   return cnt;
}
function checkDr(i,j,stone) {
   var cnt = 0;
   
   try {
      while(true) {
         i++;
         j++;
         if (arr2d[i][j] == stone) {
            cnt++;
         } else {
            return cnt;
         }
      }      
   } catch(e) {
      return cnt;
   }
   return cnt;
}
function checkDl(i,j,stone) {
   var cnt = 0;
   
   try {
      while(true) {
         i++;
         j--;
         if (arr2d[i][j] == stone) {
            cnt++;
         } else {
            return cnt;
         }
      }      
   } catch(e) {
      return cnt;
   }
   return cnt;
}

$.ajax({
    url : "ajax_insert_sawon",
    data : JSON.stringify(postdata),
    dataType : "json",
    type : "post",
    contentType : "application/json",
    async : false,
    statusCode : {
        404 : function() {
            alert("네트워크가 불안정합니다. 다시 시도부탁드립니다.");
        }
    },
    success : function(data) {
        if (data.result == "ok") {
            location.reload();
        } else {
            alert("문제 발생")
        }
        console.log(data)
    }
});


</script>
<style type="text/css">
table {
    border-spacing: 0px;
}

tr, td {
    padding: 0px;
}

img {
    display: block;
}
</style>
</head>
<body onload="myinit()">
    <input type="button" onclick="myreset()" value="리셋">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><img src="0.png" class="stn" onclick="myclick(this)"></td>
            <td><img src="0.png" class="stn" onclick="myclick(this)"></td>
            <td><img src="0.png" class="stn" onclick="myclick(this)"></td>
            <td><img src="0.png" class="stn" onclick="myclick(this)"></td>
            <td><img src="0.png" class="stn" onclick="myclick(this)"></td>

            <td><img src="0.png" class="stn" onclick="myclick(this)"></td>
            <td><img src="0.png" class="stn" onclick="myclick(this)"></td>
            <td><img src="0.png" class="stn" onclick="myclick(this)"></td>
            <td><img src="0.png" class="stn" onclick="myclick(this)"></td>
            <td><img src="0.png" class="stn" onclick="myclick(this)"></td>

            <td><img src="0.png" class="stn" onclick="myclick(this)"></td>
            <td><img src="0.png" class="stn" onclick="myclick(this)"></td>
            <td><img src="0.png" class="stn" onclick="myclick(this)"></td>
            <td><img src="0.png" class="stn" onclick="myclick(this)"></td>
            <td><img src="0.png" class="stn" onclick="myclick(this)"></td>

            <td><img src="0.png" class="stn" onclick="myclick(this)"></td>
            <td><img src="0.png" class="stn" onclick="myclick(this)"></td>
            <td><img src="0.png" class="stn" onclick="myclick(this)"></td>
            <td><img src="0.png" class="stn" onclick="myclick(this)"></td>
            <td><img src="0.png" class="stn" onclick="myclick(this)"></td>
        </tr>
...200more



    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

---

but after I try to merge the first one and socket then the ajax dosen't work anymore and it said
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:\pythonMatarials\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2450, in wsgi_app
response = self.handle_exception(e)
File "D:\pythonMatarials\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1867, in handle_exception
reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
File "D:\pythonMatarials\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\flask_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
raise value
File "D:\pythonMatarials\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2447, in wsgi_app
response = self.full_dispatch_request()
File "D:\pythonMatarials\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1952, in full_dispatch_request
rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
File "D:\pythonMatarials\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1821, in handle_user_exception
reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
File "D:\pythonMatarials\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\flask_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
raise value
File "D:\pythonMatarials\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1950, in full_dispatch_request
rv = self.dispatch_request()
File "D:\pythonMatarials\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1936, in dispatch_request
return self.view_functionsrule.endpoint
File "D:\pythonMatarials\workspace_py\HELLO_AI\day15\myflask.py", line 25, in ajax_omok
data = request.get_json()
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'get_json'

---

this is my last source

---

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify
from random import random
from flask.globals import request
from flask.templating import render_template
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model
from flask_socketio import SocketIO, send

model = load_model('models/20201213_202430.h5')
dummy_n = np.zeros((400))
dummy_n = np.reshape(dummy_n,(1,20,20,1))
model.predict(dummy_n)

app = Flask(__name__, static_url_path='', static_folder='static')
app.secret_key = "mysecret"
socket_io = SocketIO(app)

@app.route('/omok')
def omok():
    return render_template('omok05_ai_network.html')

#===============================================================================
@app.route('/ajax_omok', methods=['GET','POST'])
def ajax_omok():
    data = request.get_json()
    stones = data['stones']
    arr_stone = stones.split(',')
    print(arr_stone)
    input = []
    for s in arr_stone:
        input.append(int(s))
    
    input_n = np.array(input)
    input_n = np.reshape(input_n,(1,20,20,1))
    output = model.predict(input_n).squeeze()
    
    cnt = np.argmax(output)
    
    i = int(cnt/20)
    j = int(cnt%20)
    
    print(i,j)
    return jsonify(i = i, j = j)

@app.route('/chat')
def chatting():
    return render_template('chat_omok.html')


@socket_io.on("message")
def request(message):
    print("message : "+ message)
    to_client = dict()
    to_client['message'] = message
    send(to_client, broadcast=True)

#===============================================================================

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # app.run(host="0.0.0.0", debug=True)
    socket_io.run(app,host="0.0.0.0", debug=True, port=5000)
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>OMOK</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="socket.io.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
// var comput_i = 0;
// var computs = [
//         {"i":0,"j":0},
//         {"i":0,"j":1},
//         {"i":0,"j":2},
//         {"i":0,"j":3},
//         {"i":0,"j":4}
//     ]

var flag_wb = true;
var flag_over = false;
var arr2d = [
   [0,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,0],
   [0,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,0],
   [0,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,0],
   [0,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,0],
   [0,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,0],

   [0,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,0],
   [0,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,0],
   [0,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,0],
   [0,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,0],
   [0,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,0],
   
   [0,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,0],
   [0,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,0],
   [0,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,0],
   [0,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,0],
   [0,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,0],
   
   [0,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,0],
   [0,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,0],
   [0,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,0],
   [0,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,0],
   [0,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,0]
];

function aiinit(){

}

function myinit() {
   var stns = document.getElementsByClassName("stn");
   for(var i=0; i<20; i++) {
      for(var j=0; j<20; j++) {
         stns[i*20+j].alt = i+","+j;
      }
   }
}

function myrender() {
   var stns = document.getElementsByClassName("stn");
   for(var i=0; i<20; i++) {
      for(var j=0; j<20; j++) {
         if(arr2d[i][j] == 0) {
            stns[i*20+j].src = "0.png"
         }
         if(arr2d[i][j] == 1) {
            stns[i*20+j].src = "1.png"
         }
         if(arr2d[i][j] == 2) {
            stns[i*20+j].src = "2.png"
         }
      }
   }
}

function myreset(){
    var stns = document.getElementsByClassName("stn");
    for(var i=0; i<20; i++) {
          for(var j=0; j<20; j++) {
              arr2d[i][j]=0;
              stns[i*20+j].src = "0.png"
          }
    }
    flag_over = false;
    flag_wb = true;
}

function myclick(obj) {
   if(flag_over) {
      return;
   }
   
   var str = obj.alt;
   var arr = str.split(",");
   
   var i = parseInt(arr[0]);
   var j = parseInt(arr[1]);
   if(arr2d[i][j] > 0) {
      return;
   }
   
   var stone = -1;
   if (flag_wb) {
      arr2d[i][j] = 1;
      stone = 1;
   } else {      
      arr2d[i][j] = 2;
      stone = 2;
   }
   
   var up = checkUp(i,j,stone);
   var dw = checkDw(i,j,stone);
   var ri = checkRi(i,j,stone);
   var le = checkLe(i,j,stone);

   var ur = checkUr(i,j,stone);
   var ul = checkUl(i,j,stone);
   var dr = checkDr(i,j,stone);
   var dl = checkDl(i,j,stone);
   
   var d1 = up+dw+1;
   var d2 = le+ri+1;
   var d3 = ul+dr+1;
   var d4 = ur+dl+1;
   
   myrender();
   
   if(d1==5 || d2==5 || d3==5 || d4==5) {
      if(flag_wb) {
          setTimeout(function(){
              alert("흰돌 승리");
          },300); 
      } else {
          setTimeout(function(){
              alert("흑돌 승리");
          },300); 
      }
      
      flag_over = true;
      return
   }
   
   flag_wb = !flag_wb;
   /*==============================*/
    var stones = arr2d+"";
    stones = stones.replace(/2/gi, "-1")
    console.log(stones)
    
    var postdata = {
        'stones' : stones
    }
    var iii
    var jjj
    console.log(postdata)
    
    
    
    $.ajax({
        url : "ajax_omok",
        data : JSON.stringify(postdata),
        dataType : "json",
        type : "post",
        contentType : "application/json",
        async : false,
        statusCode : {
            404 : function() {
                alert("네트워크가 불안정합니다. 다시 시도부탁드립니다.");
            }
        },
        success : function(data) {
            console.log(data);
            console.log(data['i']);
            console.log(data['j']);
            iii = data['i']
            jjj = data['j']
        }
    });
   var i = iii;
   var j = jjj;
   
   var stone = -1;
   if (flag_wb) {
      arr2d[i][j] = 1;
      stone = 1;
   } else {      
      arr2d[i][j] = 2;
      stone = 2;
   }
   
   var up = checkUp(i,j,stone);
   var dw = checkDw(i,j,stone);
   var ri = checkRi(i,j,stone);
   var le = checkLe(i,j,stone);

   var ur = checkUr(i,j,stone);
   var ul = checkUl(i,j,stone);
   var dr = checkDr(i,j,stone);
   var dl = checkDl(i,j,stone);
   
   var d1 = up+dw+1;
   var d2 = le+ri+1;
   var d3 = ul+dr+1;
   var d4 = ur+dl+1;
   
   myrender();
   
   if(d1==5 || d2==5 || d3==5 || d4==5) {
      if(flag_wb) {
          setTimeout(function(){
              alert("흰돌 승리");
          },300); 
      } else {
          setTimeout(function(){
              alert("흑돌 승리");
          },300); 
      }
      
      flag_over = true;
      return
   }
   
   flag_wb = !flag_wb;
   comput_i++
   
   
   
   
   
   
}//end



function checkUp(i,j,stone) {
   var cnt = 0;
   
   try {
      while(true) {
         i--;
         if (arr2d[i][j] == stone) {
            cnt++;
         } else {
            return cnt;
         }
      }      
   } catch(e) {
      return cnt;
   }
   return cnt;
}
function checkDw(i,j,stone) {
   var cnt = 0;
   
   try {
      while(true) {
         i++;
         if (arr2d[i][j] == stone) {
            cnt++;
         } else {
            return cnt;
         }
      }      
   } catch(e) {
      return cnt;
   }
   return cnt;
}
function checkRi(i,j,stone) {
   var cnt = 0;
   
   try {
      while(true) {
         j++;
         if (arr2d[i][j] == stone) {
            cnt++;
         } else {
            return cnt;
         }
      }      
   } catch(e) {
      return cnt;
   }
   return cnt;
}
function checkLe(i,j,stone) {
   var cnt = 0;
   
   try {
      while(true) {
         j--;
         if (arr2d[i][j] == stone) {
            cnt++;
         } else {
            return cnt;
         }
      }      
   } catch(e) {
      return cnt;
   }
   return cnt;
}

function checkUr(i,j,stone) {
   var cnt = 0;
   
   try {
      while(true) {
         i--;
         j++;
         if (arr2d[i][j] == stone) {
            cnt++;
         } else {
            return cnt;
         }
      }      
   } catch(e) {
      return cnt;
   }
   return cnt;
}
function checkUl(i,j,stone) {
   var cnt = 0;
   
   try {
      while(true) {
         i--;
         j--;
         if (arr2d[i][j] == stone) {
            cnt++;
         } else {
            return cnt;
         }
      }      
   } catch(e) {
      return cnt;
   }
   return cnt;
}
function checkDr(i,j,stone) {
   var cnt = 0;
   
   try {
      while(true) {
         i++;
         j++;
         if (arr2d[i][j] == stone) {
            cnt++;
         } else {
            return cnt;
         }
      }      
   } catch(e) {
      return cnt;
   }
   return cnt;
}
function checkDl(i,j,stone) {
   var cnt = 0;
   
   try {
      while(true) {
         i++;
         j--;
         if (arr2d[i][j] == stone) {
            cnt++;
         } else {
            return cnt;
         }
      }      
   } catch(e) {
      return cnt;
   }
   return cnt;
}

// $.ajax({
//  url : "ajax_insert_sawon",
//  data : JSON.stringify(postdata),
//  dataType : "json",
//  type : "post",
//  contentType : "application/json",
//  async : false,
//  statusCode : {
//      404 : function() {
//          alert("네트워크가 불안정합니다. 다시 시도부탁드립니다.");
//      }
//  },
//  success : function(data) {
//      if (data.result == "ok") {
//          location.reload();
//      } else {
//          alert("문제 발생")
//      }
//      console.log(data)
//  }
// });


</script>
<style type="text/css">
table {
    border-spacing: 0px;
}

tr, td {
    padding: 0px;
}

img {
    display: block;
}
</style>
</head>
<body onload="myinit()">
    <input type="button" onclick="myreset()" value="리셋">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><img src="0.png" class="stn" onclick="myclick(this)"></td>
            <td><img src="0.png" class="stn" onclick="myclick(this)"></td>
            <td><img src="0.png" class="stn" onclick="myclick(this)"></td>
            <td><img src="0.png" class="stn" onclick="myclick(this)"></td>
            <td><img src="0.png" class="stn" onclick="myclick(this)"></td>
...200 more
</body>
</html>
```

How can I fix the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're trying to decode JSON data from a request response, you should use the following syntax:

```
r = requests.get('https://api.github.com/events')
>>> r.json()
```

From Requests library [documentation](https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#json-response-content).